# Why the built flutter app doesn't show a content?

Tags: flutter

I have build a flutter application using `flutter build web` and it makes an html with some extra files. The problem is that opening `index.html` file shows nothing but a white empty screen ...

**Update:** As dear Yeasin stated, I needed to upload the file on a server/host. Before that, `base href` should be set in the build command. If you want to upload the code on `www.foo.com/bar/` then use the command `flutter build web --base-href "/bar/"`

Comment: can you check `base href` and how opening html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a local server to view the build web-app. A simple way will be using `Live Server` extension on vscode.

Open root build on vscode workspace and then click on `go live`.

More about using [LiveServer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

Comment: Thanks Yeasin. Why do we need a server while the app is on frontend?

Comment: Actually It's an app itself, not a single html-page[website]  as you can see, it contains some js file like `main.dart.js` + others property. we need to load all those files. you can read the

Comment: I have uploaded the files on a host (a php host) and it doesn't do the job again. Is there some special requirements for the host?

Comment: not sure, try to check the base ref and error on console. I only used vscode extension for local

Comment: the base is set as follows: `<base href="https://something.com/directory/">` but the comments in the html file say that it should start and end with slashes. What is the correct form of it?

Comment: I think you dont need to provide `somethining.com` . try `<base href="/directory/">`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have updated the question with your answer